# Linux Mint 19 Tara - can only install without EFI

Tags: linux-mint, grub2, dual-boot, uefi

For the past week I've been trying to create a dual boot with Windows 10 and Linux Mint 19 Tara.

The base setup, as intended is supposed to be a simple 1 operating system per SSD:

> /dev/sda (250GB SSD) - Windows 10
>
> /dev/sdb (250GB SSD) - Linux Mint 19 Tara

All other data disks are disconnected (for the time being).

I started with installing Windows 10 (onto /dev/sda) making sure I boot of USB using UEFI. Everything went fine and looking at the partitions, I can clearly see an EFI partition.

I then proceeded to boot the Mint USB in the same manner and started install (using ERASE, Encrypt and LVM).

At some point I get prompted with:

> The 'grub-efi-amd64-signed' package failed to install into /target/. Without the GRUB boot loader, the installed system will not boot.

This results in a GRUB command-line at boot-time. When I type 'exit' it will then go on to boot Windows.

So, I started researching and found tons of articles and guides all explaining me to do exactly what I've been doing, including disabling 'Secure Boot' and 'Fast Boot' etc in the BIOS.

In my ASUS BIOS there isn't an option to disable 'Secure Boot' directly and I originally simply set the OS Type to 'Other', which works perfectly fine for installing Fedora 28 and Kali. (which I had previously installed on /dev/sdb)

This change was not enough though. So after some more research I found that in order to completely disable 'Secure Boot' I need to delete the key in BIOS. Once I had done that, 'Secure Boot' showed as disabled. Still, Linux Mint installation gave me the exact same error message and failed to install GRUB.

I then started experimenting some more including various approaches to manually setting up partitions. None of it worked and always resulted in the same issue. I eventually found that I seemingly can't install using EFI at all. The only installation that went through properly was, when I booted of the USB without UEFI (while 'Secure Boot' is disabled, obviously).

This clearly isn't what I want though and I've grown extremely frustrated. As a result of failed experimentation, I've had to reinstall Windows several times as well and we all know that's never fun, as it takes the better part of a day to fully update Windows.

I've really started to enjoy Linux Mint on my other (older) system and simply want it on my main system as well, but I'm relatively new to linux and I'm at a loss.

I sincerely hope somebody has some suggestion(s).

Please let me know if you need more information, but keep in mind that I'm fairly new to Linux in general, so be specific with any queries.

Thanks.

**Update:**
I've tried 'Boot Repair' as suggested to some Ubuntu users with similar issues, but I still only get a GRUB command-line at start up.

**Update 2:**
I decided to try another download of Linux Mint from a random mirror and noticed that today the downloaded is is called 'linuxmint-19-cinnamon-64bit**-v2**.iso'. Hopefully EFI install will work now. Will post back with results.

**FIXED**
That did it. After creating a new bootable USB from the now available 'linuxmint-19-cinnamon-64bit-**v2**.iso', the system installed just fine using EFI. Awesome! :)

Comment: Manually creating EFI partition didn't work for me, so I don't consider it a duplicate. I don't know what the changes are in the new ISO, but everything works fine now with the new ISO's installation.